# Showing both Master and Detail View in portrait mode in MGSplitViewController

Tags: ipad

I am currently integrating MGSplitViewController in one of my application and its working properly.

But i want to modify the way it is displaying currently in portrait mode.So i want in portrait mode whenever application open it should display both master as well as detail view controller.So on pressing the navigation bar button it will again hide and show the left root view controller.

So i have changed the code to

```
   - (BOOL)shouldShowMasterForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)theOrientation
    {
    // Returns YES if master view should be shown directly embedded in the splitview, instead of hidden in a popover.
    //return ((UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(theOrientation)) ? _showsMasterInLandscape : _showsMasterInPortrait);

     return YES;   
    }
```

Now both portrait and landscape mode is showing both root and detail view controller as i wants but the problem is navigation bar button is not working to hide & show left root view controller.

Any body have done this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the `MGSplitViewController` source or subclassing it, you can use the `showsMasterInPortrait` property of the `MGSplitViewController` to toggle the master on and off from your application code. This has always worked fine for me.

**Update with specifics:**

I wouldn't use the bar button item that the split view controller provides - it's not overly useful for our purposes. Instead, set up your own button, with an associated action which toggles the `showsMasterInPortrait` property of your split view controller. To get to the latter, wire up an outlet property. You'll also need an outlet for the button itself if you're going to hide the button in landscape. Make sure that's wired up correctly in IB, too.

In the header, that means something like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet MGSplitViewController* splitVC;
@property(nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem* toggleButton;
- (IBAction)toggleMasterViewTouched:(id)sender;
```

And in the class definition:

```
@synthesize splitVC, toggleButton;

- (IBAction)toggleMasterViewTouched:(id)sender
{
  BOOL master_shown = !self.splitVC.showsMasterInPortrait;
  // Note: toggle the button's label text and/or icon between "hide" and "show" versions
  self.toggleButton.title = master_shown ? @"Hide Master" : @"Show Master";

  self.splitVC.showsMasterInPortrait = master_shown;
}
```

If you only want the button to appear in portrait, you'll also need to hide it on autorotation, so respond to the rotation event (still in the detail controller):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  // hide when in landscape, show when in portrait
  self.toggleButton.hidden = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

And that should hopefully be all. You'll also want to set up defaults for showsMasterInPortrait and the toggle button label and visibility somewhere, probably in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Can you put a snippet over here what i have to do.

Comment: i have done following changes but still it is not working.. currently i m using xcode4.2... iOS5 simulator...If you have done that sample application you can post some where so that i can download it...Otherwise i can send you my code

Comment: I suggest updating the question with the crucial bits of code and explaining what exactly works, what doesn't, and what you're expecting to happen for each piece of code.